# Can't figure out why I get error when trying to get JSON value into DF

Tags: python, json, pandas

Been looking online but can't figure out why I'm getting the error as the data is available in the JSON.

I'm trying to extract "pull_request_contributors" value from JSON and put into DF.

I get the error:

```
KeyError: "Try running with errors='ignore' as key 'pull_request_contributors' is not always present"
```

**Code**

```
cg = CoinGeckoAPI()

ts = '01-01-2017'
cs = 'bitcoin'

# get data
result = cg.get_coin_history_by_id(cs, ts)

#pull_request_contributors
df_pr = pd_json.json_normalize(data, 
                            record_path='developer_data', 
                            meta=['pull_request_contributors']).set_index(ts)
```

**JSON**

```
{'community_data': {'facebook_likes': 40055,
  'reddit_accounts_active_48h': '4657.4',
  'reddit_average_comments_48h': 186.5,
  'reddit_average_posts_48h': 3.75,
  'reddit_subscribers': 1014816,
  'twitter_followers': 64099},
 'developer_data': {'closed_issues': 3845,
  'commit_count_4_weeks': 245,
  'forks': 22024,
  'pull_request_contributors': 564,
  'pull_requests_merged': 6163,
  'stars': 36987,
  'subscribers': 3521,
  'total_issues': 4478}...
```

**Expectation**

```
date        bitcoin 
01-01-2017  564
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the field pull_request_contributors is not available in each object, pandas cannot build the dataframe. Run
`df_pr = pd_json.json_normalize(data, record_path='developer_data', meta=['pull_request_contributors'], errors='ignore').set_index(ts)`
 to ignore missing fields.

**EDIT**

json_normalized creates a table with all fields as columns and their values make the rows. So for what you want to achieve, I wouldn't go with json_normalize, since you know which particular field you want to read. Here's how I would do it

```
ts = '01-01-2017'
cs = 'bitcoin'

df_pr = pd_json.json_normalize(data['developer_data'])

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[{'date': ts, 
                        cs: data['developer_data']['pull_request_contributors']}]).set_index('date')
```

This way we simply construct the DataFrame, without first normalizing the response.

If the response is a string and not a dict, I don't know what the CoinGeckoAPI returns, you can decode it first with

```
import json

data = json.loads(json_string)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Gives me this df: 
          0 pull_request_contributors                                                                                         
0 forks NaN
1 stars NaN
2 subscribers NaN
3 total_issues NaN
4 closed_issues NaN
5 pull_requests_merged NaN
6 pull_request_contributors NaN
7 commit_count_4_weeks NaN

Comment: why does it have to be available in every object?

Comment: Sorry, I'm sitting on a computer just now. I edited my original answer. Let me know if this helps